# How do I assign a server two different public IPs?

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking

I would like to add a second NIC to a Windows Server 2003 VM so that it will have two NICs which each have a different public IP.

How do I go about assigning the NICs to different public IPs?

Comment: Directions for adding the NIC would require knowing what virtualization technology you're using.

Comment: Are you trying to use a 2nd external network?  
Is this for performance?
Does it have to be a 2nd NIC or could you just add a 2nd IP to the current NIC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Shut down the VM.
2. In VMware, Hyper-V, VirtualBox, Xen, or whichever hypervisor you happen to be using, edit the VM settings.  Add a second network adapter.  Assign it to the appropriate physical interface.  Because you want it to have a public IP, be sure to use Bridged mode (not NAT or host-only).
3. Start the VM.
4. Log in as an administrator.
5. Start->Run->ncpa.cpl, right-click the new network adapter, click Properties, select TCP/IP, click Properties, assign an IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Once the NIC is installed, you should be able to give it a static IP like normal through the NIC's TCP/IP settings in control panel.

I am not completely sure if this is what you are asking, maybe clarify?

Comment: I think I just need to setup the NICs so they connect to separate gateways.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a VM, you shouldn't need to create a seperate NIC, you can just add a second IP and gateway to the virtual NIC you have installed through Windows Control Panel.